# Making Netflix-desktop more stable

Tags: kde, video, wine

I've installed netflix-desktop as per the [iheartubuntu Netflix Desktop app guide](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html). It works for about 2 hours and then crashes, taking down my KDE window manager with it.

How can I make Netflix stable?

`uname -arv` gives `3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

I have 8 GB of RAM and 4 GB of swap.

Answer (score 1):

Short of ensuring your drivers are properly installed and your netflix-desktop installation is properly installed, I'm not sure what else you actually can do short of contributing.  Also, check to see if any errors pertaining to netflix-desktop appear in your ~/.xsession-errors log file.

If you're having problems, I'd recommend that you try reinstalling and keeping your machine up to date.

I have had no issues running the application using Ubuntu.

Comment: I've found no mention of Netflix-desktop in .xsession-errors now looking for the dependancies.

Comment: It seems to be most crash prone when in fullscreen so I'm running it windowed.

Comment: You are sure that its Netflix causing the crash and not a driver issue?

Comment: >  It seems to be most crash prone when in fullscreen  
>  so I'm running it windowed.

Based on that comment, I'd say you might want to check your window manager options as well as the compiz configurations.

Comment: Compiz _is_ the window manager.